# Using NETLink.MathKernel.Compute() for graphics results fails with GraphPlot[]

Tags: graphics, programming, mathlink-or-wstp

I'm using MMA 8.0 to provide backend on a .NET application I'm writing.  I am trying to use the high-level `Wolfram.NETLink.MathKernel` interface to export an image created with GraphPlot[].

Although the Result comes back as '-Graphics-', I find that Graphics[] is empty.  Changing the Compute() to another graphic generating command returns an image in the Graphic[] as expected.

Here's my example code:

```
Wolfram.NETLink.IKernelLink _iKernelLink;

string cmdLine = "-linkmode launch -linkname \"C:/Program Files/Wolfram Research/Mathematica/8.0/MathKernel.exe\"";
_iKernelLink = Wolfram.NETLink.MathLinkFactory.CreateKernelLink(cmdLine);
_iKernelLink.WaitAndDiscardAnswer();

var k = new Wolfram.NETLink.MathKernel(_iKernelLink); // new MathKernel

k.AutoCloseLink = true; // close link when object is disposed
k.CaptureGraphics = true; // capture graphics output
k.CapturePrint = true; // capture print output
k.CaptureMessages = true; // capture messages
k.HandleEvents = true; // lets Compute thread handle application events
k.UseFrontEnd = false; // don't use Mathematica Notebook front-end

// this produces empty Graphic[] result
string command = @"GraphPlot[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 1, 3 -> 1, 3 -> 2, 4 -> 1, 4 -> 2, 4 -> 4}]";

// this command produces the expected Graphic[] result
//string command = @"BarChart@Range[5]";

k.Compute(command);

if (k.Graphics.Length > 0) // <-- should be an image for both commands
    return k.Graphics[0];
else
    return null;
```

Comment: I have just seen that you use UseFrontEnd = false; I could very well imagine that some parts of the Graph rendering need a frontend, so I'd try to set that to yes when experimenting...

Comment: Hello James and welcome to the Mathematica StackExchange. We are a pretty friendly bunch! Don't forget to upvote good answers (and other people's questions) using the triangle above the number next to the post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your problem is that Graph will actually not evaluate to a Graphics but only be rendered as something like that by the FrontEnd. You could look at `ToBoxes[yourgraph]` to learn some details and try to extract something that can be transfered to .NET. I don't have any experience with NETLink, but I remember that at least older versions of JLink would return graphics as rastered images anyway, so a more simple approach could be to use

```
Rasterize[GraphPlot[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 1, 3 -> 1, 3 -> 2, 4 -> 1, 4 -> 2, 4 -> 4}]]
```

You might want to finetune this with the options of Rasterize to meet your needs.

Comment: `Show` will convert Graph to Graphics: try `Show@Graph[{1 -> 2}]`.

Comment: @Szabolcs: good point, I tried to find the function to do that but didn't find the most obious (tried `Normal` and some others). Why don't you make that an answer, isn't it just exactly what the OP needs? I'll be happy to add it to mine otherwise :-)

Comment: I tried both `Show` and `Rasterize`.  Interestingly, both cause a front-end to open (in spite of `UseFrontEnd` setting), but only `Show` seems to actually work (i.e., `Graphics[]` result is filled with the GraphPlot).

Comment: @Szabolcs This has helped me. I think this should be an answer rather than a comment.